# Automator Workflow Finder Tags

Tags: python, terminal, applescript

I have thousands of photos in lightroom that I am converting to JPEG to save space. The thing is that these RAW files are already categorized into different finder label tags, so when I export to JPEG these labels will be removed. Is there a way to keep these tags or just create an automator workflow that scans a directory and finds JPEG with the exact filename as the .CR2/.NEF extension and applies the tags to the newly JPEG files?

macOS Sierra

Mac Pro (Late 2013)

3.7 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon E5

Version 10.12.3 (16D32)

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow is not a place where you ask someone to develop something for you. You should start your program and then you can get help from here. So here is some help :

1) there is no standard Automator action to get or set labels. But Applescript contains function about labels.

2) However, please be aware that Applescript capabilities are, today, limited to a single color label per file even if you can set multiple in Finder. So if you have set multiple color labels per CR2 or NEF file, Applescript can't help you yet

3) you need to build a "repeat" loop through your JPEG files and for each, extract the name without extension. This can be done via:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set N to name of aFile
    set Ext to name extension of aFile
    set BaseName to text 1 thru ((length of N) - (length of Ext) - 1) of N
end tell
```

4) you must use that name to add the 2 possible extensions (CR2, NEF) and search if the file exists in raw folder. You can do that by using Finder function "exists"

5) if CR2/NEF file exists get the label and set it to your jpeg file using file attribute "label index":

```
set myLabel to label index of file CR2 -- to read CR2 file label
set label index of aFile to myLabel -- to assign the label found to your new jpg file
```

6) because your Jpg files are in same folders/sub folder as raw file, you just need to select a single folder containing all files. For each jpg, you search, at same folder level, if raw file exists. The folder containing a file is called by "container". to get files from all sub folder levels use "entire contents". I just add a filter to only get files with extension "JPG" or "jpg". You may have to extend the list to your extensions.

All together it gives :

```
-- possible values label index: 0= no label, 1=orange, 2=Red, 3=yellow, 4=blue, 5=pink, 6=green, 7=grey
set myFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select folder containing JPEG and raw files"

tell application "Finder"
set JPEGFiles to every file in entire contents of folder myFolder whose name extension is in {"JPG", "jpg"}
repeat with aFile in JPEGFiles -- loop through all jpeg files
    -- extract name of Jpg file without extension
    set N to name of aFile
    set Ext to name extension of aFile
    set parentFolder to (container of aFile) as string -- get folder
    set BaseName to text 1 thru ((length of N) - (length of Ext) - 1) of N
    -- build possible raw file names with extension .CR2 or .NEF
    set CR2 to (parentFolder & BaseName & ".CR2") as string
    set NEF to (parentFolder & BaseName & ".NEF") as string

    -- search existing label and assign it to jpg file
    set myLabel to 0 -- default no label
    if CR2 exists then set myLabel to label index of file CR2 -- get label of .CR2 if exists
    if NEF exists then set myLabel to label index of file NEF -- get label of .NEF if exists
    if myLabel > 0 then set label index of aFile to myLabel -- if label found, assignment to jpg file
end repeat -- loop to next file in jpg folder
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you put it all together for me? I'm not sure where the two pieces of code combine

Comment: script added in first answer.

Comment: Great! Works perfect. Now I need it to include all sub folders also. Possible?

Comment: yes possible. easy for jpeg folder adding "entire content of". But less easy to search Row files in subfolders, except if you're sure sub folders structure is exactly same for Raw and JPg

Comment: Yes, They are exactly the same. The JPEG and RAW files are in the same directory

Comment: script has been updated taking into account the fact that all raw and all jpg are in same directories.